# Declare or "cast" to actual type in Python when returning 'any' from function

Tags: python

Function that I'm consuming returns `any` as type and I can't get suggestions in the code.

How can I make my `core_client` variable be of the actual type `<CoreClient> <azure.devops.released.core.core_client.CoreClient>`?

I tried looking into [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-any-type) specification but couldn't find a guide for it there.

What are the options to make it work?

This is the SDK function I'm calling:

```py
def get_core_client(self):
    """get_core_client.
    Gets the 5.1 version of the CoreClient
    :rtype: :class:`<CoreClient> <azure.devops.released.core.core_client.CoreClient>`
    """
    return self._connection.get_client('azure.devops.released.core.core_client.CoreClient')
```

I can't get any suggestions, seems like the `any` return type is the cause:

```py
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
core_client.*** # no suggestions here
```

SDK is from https://pypi.org/project/azure-devops/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`core_client:CoreClient = connection.clients.get_core_client()`

then you should get hints.... (depending on your IDE)

typically ides *also* understand isinstance

if you add `assert isinstance(core_client,CoreClient)` **most** IDE's will
(*some* will recognize a block of `if isinstance(core_client,CoreClient):`) and pick this up as well, but generally its not a great idea to use asserts in production code (but you can...)

keep in mind of coarse specifying types does not specify any kind of enforceable contract(`core_client:CoreClient = ...`) is really just for syntax assistance (and autodoc stuff...)